# Converting from Binary to NSData and to Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert binary to `NSData`, and I am able to get data but uiimage is still nil. Below is my code. Please can anyone help me on this.

```
NSData *data = [self dataFromBase64EncodedString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"object"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

-(NSData *)dataFromBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string{
    if (string.length > 0) {
      NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:;base64,%@", string];
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data64URLString]];
      return data;
     }
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible. Xcode has no built-in NSData-to-image conversion facilities. Maybe you meant to do the conversion **in your own application?**

Comment: Have you debugged the code you posted? Have you looked at each value along the way?

Comment: Yeah i am getting data converted to bytes exactly as database but UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; here the image is nil not getting.

Answer (score -1):

Your url seems to be missing the base url.

```
  NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:;base64,%@", string];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data64URLString]];
```

Based on the above.. the url is set to "data:;base64,

shouldnt it be something like "http://my.server.com/imageurl"

Comment: if this wasnt correct, `data` would be nil. But OP confirmed it does exists.

Comment: Still the url scheme doesnt look right - Apple Doc says it should be data://.. thats what threw me off .. It might be returning the data but we cant be sure its the correct data..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURL - RFC 1808

Comment: apples doc does not mention that the scheme has to be set (it is just mentioned in a side note to show that protocols do not have to be networking protocols), rfc 1808 doesn't  mention it at all.

Comment: `base:` is a sufficient scheme: *The full URL is the concatenation of the scheme, a colon (:), and the value of resourceSpecifier.*